# How to prevent a laravel queue job from going into failed queue

Tags: laravel, message-queue

I have a queue job that should retry a few times but after certain number of retries instead of going into failed queue, it should just be cancelled.
All other jobs should still go to failed queue.

How can I do it in Laravel?

Comment: But the failed jobs table in the database, doesn't have any action behind that? they are just laying there for logging purpose so what is wrong with it being there?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The failed jobs table is meant to be for logging purposes only (as @mrhn mentioned) so if you are actually using that table for other purposes then you are trying to force a purpose on it that it was not intended to have. Instead you probably want another means of doing what you need to do (whatever that may be)

Comment: I am using Horizon, which has the option to retry a job. 
So I can retry a failed job if needed.
Except that specific one job simply becomes outdated if it fails, so retrying it makes no sense, plus it will fail only if another job fails, so I already have the failure logged.

Comment: I cannot edit my question, so let me explain in here.
I have a CI system with 2 jobs: `Update` (actually many jobs/steps) and `UpdateLater`.
Every time a push happens to the repo (many times per hour) `UpdateLater` is put into the queue. `UpdateLater` will check if there is update in progress and if not it will start one. If there is an update then it will delay itself by 1 minute (put back to queue).
But there is a use case where if `Update` fails, then `UpdateLater` will simply timeout after 10 attempts, causing a spam of failed `UpdateLater`s that I have to deal with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue it is not recommended, but more as a way to practical achieve what you want. How the failed jobs are saved is determined by the queue config failed driver setting, you can change these while your job is running.

This can be set in the job you want to avoid going to the `failed_jobs` table.

```
class JobThatShouldNotReportToFailedJobs
{
    public function handle()
    {
        config()->set('queue.failed.driver', null);
    }
}
```

Comment: This will prevent all jobs from going to failed, and I want only prevent a single job from going to failed.

Comment: you can set it in the context of a single job

Comment: Does Laravel bootstrap the app again on each job? My point is, for the next job, the same queue worker, will it has the old queue.failed.driver?